# nested for not working as intended in java

Tags: java, c#, c++, for-loop

I want to sum the elements of 2 different lists.

in my test list 1 contains 1 and 2 
and list 2 contains 3 and 4. 
I want to sum the elements of list 1 and list 2 like this: 
1+3, 1+4, 2+3, 2+4.

I've tried the code below,
but it does not work.

my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l2.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println( l1.get(i) + l2.get(i) );
        }
    }
```

my output always shows

```
5
5
5
5
```

kindly help and correct me if im wrong or missed the logic.

Comment: Your code uses `i` twice, instead of using `i` and `j`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: oops. thanks for help. how did i forget this.

Comment: @Dev Do you need 4 numbers `4`, `5`, `5`, and `6`, or do you need one number `20`?

Comment: i need it as 4, 5, 5 , 6. i found my mistake. should replace i with j at the second list.

Comment: but that will increment right ?

Comment: I tryed to improve the question a bit,
because I feel many beginners struggle with this and use the naming pattern blindly and my provided answer may be helpful to beginners. I added c++ and c# as tags, because the error is language independant and beginners tend to search for their programming language only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use j at some point, at which you should be able to figure out yourself

this is a very common error with starters I guess, because using "i" becomes a unquestioned habit

to avoid this problem you could start using another naming pattern,

eg. call them it1 and it2 when iterating lists, and x y when traversing coordinates etc., this way you know what you intended to do with them

this also can improve readability a lot,
if you ever have to refine a complex nested for you will curse at not using better names

you might want to consider using the refactoring (in eclipse strg+1 and "rename in file") to give the iterators a more meaningful name afterwards, or if you get confused midway through the algorithm even beforehand

Comment: I added a bit to the answer, the hints provided may be useful